# 32-bit iOS 9 simulator doesn't recognize my custom framework's classes while 64-bit is just fine

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, 32bit-64bit, xcode9

I have an iOS project and the project is divided into separate targets: one for the app itself, one for the UI Components (as I use IB Designables a lot). Everything runs perfect on all 64-bit simulators regardless of iOS version, and perfectly on my device (iPhone 7 Plus, which is 64-bit for the sake of completeness).

However, today I've tried to run my app on a 32-bit simulator (iPhone 5 and iPhone 4s simulators with iOS 9.0) and my app crashes. When I view the log I can see what's going on:

```
2017-10-31 20:06:32.624 Build 2105[16101:2403588] Unknown class ULButton in Interface Builder file.
2017-10-31 20:06:32.626 Build 2105[16101:2403588] Unknown class ULButton in Interface Builder file.
2017-10-31 20:06:32.626 Build 2105[16101:2403588] Unknown class ULButton in Interface Builder file.
2017-10-31 20:06:32.677 Build 2105[16101:2403588] Failed to set (cornerRadius) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x79374820> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key cornerRadius.
2017-10-31 20:06:32.677 Build 2105[16101:2403588] Failed to set (borderWidth) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x79374820> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key borderWidth.
2017-10-31 20:06:32.678 Build 2105[16101:2403588] Failed to set (borderColor) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x79374820> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key borderColor.
2017-10-31 20:06:32.678 Build 2105[16101:2403588] Failed to set (cornerRadius) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x7957ff80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key cornerRadius.
2017-10-31 20:06:32.679 Build 2105[16101:2403588] Failed to set (borderWidth) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x7957ff80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key borderWidth.
2017-10-31 20:06:32.679 Build 2105[16101:2403588] Failed to set (borderColor) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x7957ff80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key borderColor.
2017-10-31 20:06:32.679 Build 2105[16101:2403588] Failed to set (cornerRadius) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x790786e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key cornerRadius.
2017-10-31 20:06:32.679 Build 2105[16101:2403588] Failed to set (borderWidth) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x790786e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key borderWidth.
2017-10-31 20:06:32.680 Build 2105[16101:2403588] Failed to set (borderColor) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x790786e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key borderColor.
2017-10-31 20:06:32.683 Build 2105[16101:2403588] -[UIView addParallaxEffect]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f4e39e0
2017-10-31 20:06:32.684 Build 2105[16101:2403588] Unhandled exception occured.
```

`ULButton`, is my custom designable subclass of `UIButton` that I've *defined in my framework* with `cornerRadius`, `borderWidth` etc properties. The same goes for my custom category for `UIView` which adds `addParallaxEffect` method: it's defined in my framework, resulting in a runtime crash when not found.

I'm facing the problem when I try my app on 32-bit simulator. 64-bit simulators and 64-bit devices are just fine (I don't have access to a 32-bit device so I can't test on that). Both my app target and framework targets have the following build settings:

[image]

I've tried setting the `Build active architecture only` (just trying to see if it's related or not) to `NO` for all targets but I've got all sorts of linker errors from my dependencies, so I've reverted it. I've then tried setting it to `NO` only for the offending framework, but no avail: I still get the same error.

How can I make my framework run on 32-bit simulators?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Don't remember. 32-bit support is long gone now and I'm not supporting 32-bit anymore on any apps that I'm building so I honestly don't know what (if any) was the solution.